# Ember.js working with async relationship inside the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models:

```
App.Center = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    studies: DS.hasMany('study', {async: true})
});

App.Study = DS.Model.extend({
    center: DS.belongsTo('center'),
    //other data
});
```

In theory, Ember will wait for the studies promise to be resolved and then render the template to display them. For the common scenarios this is very good.

I must implement some filtering and other operations on the Center's studies inside the `CenterStudiesController`.

The problem is that `center.get('studies')` is an empty array inside the controller. How could I wait for them to be loaded?

I don't want to modify the server code in order to sideload the studies.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises could be resolved in routes (in model, beforeModel or afterModel hooks).If the model hook (or the related beforeModel or afterModel hooks) returns a promise (or if a promise was provided as an argument to transitionTo), the transition will pause until that promise fulfills or rejects.

The values passed to the setupController hook for each route will be the fulfilled values from the promises. http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_the-router-pauses-for-promises

You could resolve `center.studies` in route as model. In CenterStudies controller `model` will be resolved array of `studies`.

```
//center studies route
model: function() {
   var center = this.modelFor('center'); // or something else it depends on your logic
   return center.get('studies');
}

// center studies controller
filteredStudies: Ember.computed('model.[]', function() {
  // your filtering here
})

// center studies template
{{#each filteredStudies as |study|}}
   {{study.data}} 
{{/each}}
```